# Combination of \qedhere and \tag on the left

Tags: horizontal-alignment, luatex, amsthm

If I put a `\qedhere` in combination with `\tag{2}` but on the left I get an error:
Package amsmath Error: Multiple \tag.
The error also say to copnsult the documenation, thing I did and put a `\mbox` around `\qedhere` which eliminated the rror but as you can see, I have a bad alignement, the box is not at the end of the line:

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\leqnos}{\tagsleft@true\let\veqno\@@leqno}
\newcommand{\reqnos}{\tagsleft@false\let\veqno\@@eqno}
\reqnos
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{Some}
\section{Introduction}

\begin{lemma} \label{lem:lemma1}
Without error but no \verb|\qedhere|
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}
We have
\leqnos \begin{gather*}
\tag{1}
3=2+1\\
\tag{2}
2=1 +1
\end{gather*}
\end{proof}

\begin{lemma} \label{lem:lemma2}
No error but bad alignement
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}
We have
\leqnos \begin{gather*}
\tag{1}
3=2+1\\
\tag{2}
2=1 +1
\mbox{\qedhere}
\end{gather*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem if you do that with `ntheorem` (and an automatic placement of the qed symbol).

*Note*: If you load `ntheorem` with option `amsthm`, you only have to define the `lemma` environment.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

 \usepackage[thmmarks, thref, amsmath]{ntheorem}
 \theoremstyle{plain}
 \theoremheaderfont{\bfseries}
 \theorembodyfont{\mdseries}
\theoremseparator{.}
 \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
 \newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
 \theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
 \theoremheaderfont{\itshape}
 \theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\Box}}
 \newtheorem{proof}{Proof}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\leqnos}{\tagsleft@true\let\veqno\@@leqno}
\newcommand{\reqnos}{\tagsleft@false\let\veqno\@@eqno}
\reqnos
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Some}
\section{Introduction}

\begin{lemma} \label{lem:lemma1}
Without error but no \verb|\qedhere|
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}
We have
\leqnos \begin{gather*}
\tag{1}
3=2+1\\
\tag{2}
2=1 +1
\end{gather*}
\end{proof}

\begin{lemma} \label{lem:lemma2}
No error but bad alignment
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}
We have
\leqnos
 \begin{gather}
\tag{1}
3=2+1\\
\tag{2}
2=1 +1
\end{gather}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I can't upvote you. Do you mean I will never need qedhere again?

Comment: Yes, provided  there's a space between your text  and  `\end{proof}` . Also you can change the end-of-proof symbol: if you prefer `Q.E.D.` or even `E.O.Δ.`, declare it with `\theoremsymbol{…}`.