# ntheorem with thmmarks causes strange vertical spacing with amsmath equation*

Tags: amsmath, theorems, vertical-spacing, ntheorem

I experience a strange spacing before \begin{equation*} when using amsmath and ntheorem with the thmmarks option. It is associated with using leqno and fleqn together as general setting.
How do I fix this?

```
\documentclass[leqno,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thmmarks,amsmath,standard]{ntheorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{Definition}
The space below this line is called huge.
\begin{equation*}
E = m c^2
\end{equation*}
This is the last line of the definition.
\end{Definition}

The space below this line is huge.
\begin{equation*}
E = m c^2
\end{equation*}
The space below this line is normal.
\begin{equation}
E = m c^2
\end{equation}
Last line of the document.

\end{document}
```

I get the following output:

[image: picture showing the strange spacing]

Comment: looks like a ntheorem bug to me. It doesn't handle leqno correctly in this case. Report it.

Comment: My advice is to not use `ntheorem`.

Comment: How is a bug report filed? There is no current email address of Wolfgang May available to contact the author directly.

Comment: @egreg I understand also from your other posts that you don't recommend ntheorem. Which other theorem package is able to decently place the endmarks? amsthm does not do it and many manual \qedhere fixes are required.

Comment: @PeterH *I never drink wine*. Er, wrong quote: I never end a proof with a formula.

Comment: @egreg. Might be, and that is your personal decision (and maybe advanced typographical style). The manual intervention applies also to lists, not only formulae. Sometimes I like to do it my ugly way.

Comment: @PeterH I don't think that adding `\qedhere` at the end of a couple of lists is such a burden.

Comment: @egreg "amsthm" and "\qedhere" is not a solution because it has severe issues with the "leqno" option. See e. g.  [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/581038/combination-of-qedhere-and-tag-on-the-left) or [link](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/783). More issues could be easily added. Enforcing a closing text line on the author is surely not the intention of "amsthm" - otherwise "\qedhere" would not exist.

Comment: there is a email in the documentation and a few months ago it worked fine.

Comment: The email address still works. I tried it yesterday. However, the package owner's answer is slightly discouraging. In the last 10+ years his priorities have shifted (and he is annoyed that amsmath changes broke what once worked). He promised to add the issue to his (long) to-do list.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the following code works around the issue, if the `leqno` and `flteq` options are given. At least my tested examples are as expected. It may break other things.

This is just a workaround. The proper fix is very likely different.

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{equation*}{%
  \mathdisplay@push
  \st@rredtrue \global\@eqnswfalse
  \mathdisplay{equation*}%
  \global\tag@true
  \make@df@tag@@{}%
}{%
  \endmathdisplay{equation*}%
  \mathdisplay@pop
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\makeatother
```

The lines

```
\global\tag@true
\make@df@tag@@{}%
```

have been added to the original definition.